# pass a number value to a Timer, XML and AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I want to pass a number value to a Timer. How do I do this? My number and integer values for other variables work fine.

**Error**
I get *null object reference* and *coercion of value*, because I'm not passing to 'timer' properly. I don't want to say my variable's a number, I want to say it has a number value.

**Variable**

```
//what I have now 
var timer:Timer;
timer = new Timer(100);
```

**Path**

```
myXML.COUNT.text();
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SESSION>
       <TIMER TITLE="speed">100</TIMER>
</SESSION>
```

**Parse and Load**

```
//LOAD XML
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("time.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

//PARSE XML
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
```

**Working Variables** if I had a value called 'COUNT' in my XML

```
var count:int = 0;//give it a value type
count = myXML.COUNT.text();//tell it what value to receive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your XML above you can turn your value into a number like so:

```
var speed:Number = Number( myXML.TIMER.text() );
```

Now if you want to use that number to change the timer duration you can either do it like so:

```
var speed:Number = Number( myXML.TIMER.text() );
timer = new Timer( speed );
```

or you can do it after the timer was already created:

```
var speed:Number = Number( myXML.TIMER.text() );
timer.delay = speed;
```